# Return value from .aspx to .aspx.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables

I'm passing the value of a variable in my.aspx.cs file to my .aspx file. When its in the aspx, the value of it gets changed and then needs to be returned back to the .aspx.cs file. However, it won't let me change the value of the variable. Any suggestions?

.cs

```
       private string dateLookup;
    public string DateLookup
    {
        get { return dateLookup; }
        set { dateLookup = value; }
    }
```

.aspx

```
    <script runat="server">
    void Selection_Change(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       "<%=DateLookup %>" = monthList.SelectedItem.Value;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: @SLaks has it. The <%= %> syntax is used to render a variable's value to the HTML output. Referencing the variable itself is just done by name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can assign the property like any other property:

```
DateLookup = something;
```

The `<%= ... %>` syntax is used to print any value on to the page.

Answer (score 0):

the event should also be in your code behind (cs)

```
void Selection_Change(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateLookup = monthList.SelectedItem.Value;
}
```

the <%=DateLookup %> notation does not assign something, it outputs it to the html

Comment: It's not liking it. I have that method in both my .cs and my .aspx, and it's still giving me an error.

Comment: Oh I know what my problem is! I was passing over the wrong value :D It was the name of the month, not the numerical date!

Comment: I couldn't really tell what was going on at first, it looked like a bunch of gibberish. I'm new to .NET, so I wasn't used to where the errors were displaying!